# Why is the input still a string type after running it through a function to turn it into a float?

Tags: python, cs50

I type a time like 7:30 run it through the convert() function to turn that into a float that would equal 7.5. Then call it back to main() and check what type it is now, and it gives me it's still a str not a float.

```
def main():
    meal_time = input("What time is it?").strip()   
    convert(meal_time)
    print(type(meal_time))

def convert(time):
    hour, minu = time.split(":") 
    hour = float(hour) #7.0
    minu = float(minu) / 60 
    return float(hour+minu)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Input

```
7:30
```

Output

```
type 'str'
```

Comment: You're calling `convert()`, but you're not saving the returned value...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're not updating `meal_time` in `main()` with the float returned from `convert()`. Functions in Python don't modify the original variable unless it's [mutable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mutability) and you're explicitly changing it.

Instead of:

```
convert(meal_time)
```

Try:

```
meal_time = convert(meal_time)
```

**Output you should observe after the above change:**

```
<class 'float'>
```